# Reloading Collection View when returning to previous View Controller

Tags: swift, swift3

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LevelSelectCVC


    cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]


    if indexPath.item >= stageProgress {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Lock Icon Grey")
    } else {
        cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
    }

    return cell
}
```

In this function I check the value of the integer `stageProgress` and add the same amount of images from an `UIImage` array to the `collection view cells`. The remaining of the cells adds a default `UIImage`. After returning from another `view controller` I have to check the `stageProgress` and add another `UIImage` from the array.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I have tried to do:

```
self.CollectionView.reloadData()
```

In both ViewDidAppear and PrepareForSegue

If I restart the game collectionView updates.

Comment: Hope you have make sure imageArray is loaded before you are calling self.CollectionView.reloadData()

Comment: so what is your problem? reloadData is not working or it is not being called?

Comment: Check if ViewDidAppear and PrepareForSegue methods are being called when you come back from other view to this view.

Comment: ViewDidAppear are being called but nothing happens to the collection view. When trying to reloadData() in prepareForSegue the game crashes and i get an error saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: please show some error and update your question cause it is not detailed (show your detailed code)

Comment: I'm guessing maybe your IBOutlet is an optional or something and you didn't set it in interface builder but you did link the interface builder collectionView delegate and dataSource which would cause it to load by default on load but not by explicit reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling ViewDidLoad() in ViewDidAppear resolved the issue.